# Why won't Python return my mysql-connector cursor from a function?

Tags: python, python-2.7, mysql-connector

Python (2.7.3) is violating my mysql-connector cursor in some strange way when I return it from a function. This first example works fine...

```
cnx = connect()
sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
cursor = cnx.cursor()
cursor.execute(sql)
row = cursor.fetchone()
```

However, if I return the cursor and attempt the fetchone() (or a fetchall()) from outside, it throws an exception...

```
def run_query():
    cnx = connect()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    return cursor

mycursor = run_query()
row = mycursor.fetchone()
```

It throws...

```
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 533, in fetchone
  row = self._fetch_row()
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mysql/connector/cursor.py", line 508, in _fetch_row
  (row, eof) = self.db().protocol.get_row()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'protocol'
```

This is in spite of the fact that "print type(mycursor)" will print "mysql.connector.cursor.MySQLCursor"

What type of unholy molestation is Python performing on objects returned from functions? (Keep in mind that it will do this to cursors passed *within* a module... so, it's not like the object passed out of the "import mysql.connector" scope... )

Comment: Is cnx auto closing when going out of scope, thus invalidating the cursor?

Comment: Oh boy... I kinda knew that this was going to end with me yelling "F*cking Python!", like I always do. So, you mean to tell me that Python releases all of the connection's resources *even* when cursor still has references to it? How is this not akin to the dangling pointers that we thought we had left behind in the C/C++ days?

Comment: Okay, that was a bit of a rant. But, besides that, how come this problem still happens if I use:
  cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered = True)
Shouldn't a buffered cursor cause the cursor to grab all of the rows at the time of the query? If so, then what is the connection still needed for?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not have MySQL immediately available, but as Preet Sangha mentioned, when you connect to the database inside the function and return the cursor, your `cnx` variable goes out of scope when the function exits, so the database connection closes and your cursor references a closed database connection.

This is not the case in your top code example, which may explain why it works and why the bottom example does not.

Comment: Is there any way of encapsulating the database connection into a function and returning the cursor, avoiding it from going out of scope?

Answer (score 0):

Can you print type(connect) in your function?

Sample:

```
>>> import MySQLdb as mydb
>>> def runQuery(sql):
...     db = mydb.connect('localhost', 'testuser', 'test', 'test')
...     cur = db.cursor()
...     cur.execute(sql)
...     data = cur.fetchall()
...     print "Query :: %s"  %sql
...     print "Result:: %s" %data
...     return cur
...
>>>
>>> cursor = runQuery("SELECT VERSION()")
Query :: SELECT VERSION()
Result:: ('5.6.11-log',)
>>>
>>> cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEES")
3L
>>> data = cursor.fetchall()
>>>
>>> print data
(('JOHN', 30L, 23000.0), ('SONY', 26L, 14000.0), ('SMITH', 53L, 123000.0))
>>>
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer from mdscruggs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16514714/1201863) is sort of right, but it's not normal for something to get garbage-collected when exiting a function! This is not a "Python problem" [as you state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514431/why-wont-python-return-my-mysql-connector-cursor-from-a-function/76577345#comment23711535_16514431) but some design choice of MySQL's that is not common Python practice so far as my experience goes.

**Problem:** the reference to the connection is a *weak* reference.

```py
def run_query():
    ... as in your example ...
mycursor = run_query()
print(mycursor.__dict__)  # this prints the fields available in that object
```

This prints:
`{'_cnx': <weakproxy at 0x7f28aaaa8dd8 to CMySQLConnection at 0x7f28aaaa6cf8>, ...}`

From the weakref documentation:

> A weak reference to an object is not enough to keep the object alive: when the only remaining references to a referent are weak references, garbage collection is free to destroy the referent

In my case, I stored the connection in a class actually, but my problem was that I did not store a reference to the class, basically like this:
`cur = DB(config).setup().get_cursor();`
`cur.execute(...)`
I was rather puzzled that it would survive after returning from `__init__`, work fine in `setup()`, but then not be usable outside the `DB` class. What was it that triggered the class exit? Turns out, it's not the class 'exiting' that caused the problem, but the reference being gone as soon as the chain (`DB().setup().get_cursor()`) finished executing, which cascades to garbage-collecting that connection because the weakref in the cursor object does not keep it alive.

**Solution:** Keep a reference to the database connection around:

```py
def run_query():
    cnx = connect()
    sql = "SELECT * FROM MyTable"
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    return cnx, cursor

cnx, mycursor = run_query()
row = mycursor.fetchone()
```

I wonder if it might be possible to override the `_cnx` and replace it with a firm(?) reference rather than a weak one, so one does not need to keep useless variables around such that *another* function can use *its* reference...

<sub>As an aside, I would recommend better variable names than `cnx` and `mycursor`; I use them in the answer to stay consistent with the question.</sub>

**Alternative:** It looks like `pymysql` would not have this problem: they [store a normal object reference in the cursor](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/dbf1ff52a695278cd80e179641f67bb6e2a83326/pymysql/cursors.py#L35). I keep running into problems with official Oracle MySQL stuff that I do not have with alternatives such as MariaDB or in this case a pure Python library that does not call into MySQL's C connector.