# Python MySQL - Returning Cursor and Connection from Function

Tags: python, mysql

Previously I've always used something like...

```
def getConn():
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='user', password='pass',
                                      host='hostIP',
                                      database='database')
    cur = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)
    return [cnx, cur]
```

To return cnx and cur objects for use. That works fine.

I now need to use an SSH connection to a DB.

The example below executes the query within the function, but won't return the cnx or cur objects for use afterwards, so I get a print of the result, followed by the error

> mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

I appear to be having the same issue (although a different error returned) to [Why won't Python return my mysql-connector cursor from a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514431/why-wont-python-return-my-mysql-connector-cursor-from-a-function)

That question deals with why - I'd like to know if there is a solution.

```
def returnConnect():
    mypkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file('/Users/me/.ssh/id_rsa')
    sql_hostname = '127.0.0.1'

    with SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port)) as tunnel:

        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(host='127.0.0.1', user=sql_username,
                passwd=sql_password, db=sql_main_database,
                port=tunnel.local_bind_port)
        cur = cnx.cursor(buffered=True)

        sql = "select * from table"
        cur.execute(sql)
        result = cur.fetchall()
        print result
        return [cnx, cur]

conn =  returnConnect()
cnx = conn[0]
cur = conn[1]
sql = "select * from table"
cur.execute(sql)
result = cur.fetchall()
cnx.close()
print result
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python calls special method `__exit__` after `with..as` execution, so your connection closes after returning from the context of `with`. Assign the tunnel forvarder to a variable like follow and you`ll be able to use the connection outside the function scope

```
tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
        (ssh_host, ssh_port),
        ssh_username=ssh_user,
        ssh_pkey=mypkey,
        remote_bind_address=(sql_hostname, sql_port))
```

Read more about compound `with` statement [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement).

Comment: Yes - that works great. Will read up on `with` and also good practise regarding opening and closing the SSH tunnel.